# Confused. What`s the fastest way to update / upload content for a News Website?

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, content-management-system

**Hello** **guys**! first of all, I`m a **noob** in programming, have been learning
about 2 months+ now.

I`m currently half way coding a news / blogging website (e.g Mashable) using HTML, CSS, Javascript, Php (coding it from scratch to learn).

But Im kinda confuse now,
as far as I know, If I`m not going to use any type of CMS (e.g Wordpess). I will have to use a FTP software like FileZila.

1. If I need to update the website every hour, is it better to create it under Wordpress or Drupal?
2. If Im going to use FTP to update, wouldn`t it be time consuming to create a new html file and insert all the necessary tags again and again every time u need to post a news? How do people usually do it?

Sorry for the really noob question. **Will appreciate any answers and advice on this, thank you!!**

Comment: you can create tinyMce ( or other WsyWig ) editable content, without the CMS, it's just Javascrip, php, and a DB after all.

Comment: This is exactly what CMS are made for - managing bunch of content in a relatively easy way. What kind will you be using depends on you. Also your question is better suited for [su].

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to use a CMS - it could be any CMS like WordPress or Drupal or some other.
You will need to upload the files via FTP every now & then, which although manageable, is cumbersome. Using a CMS would give you the opportunity to scale your news website in future to do numerous things, for example set featured news items, or allow different people to contribute articles & so on.
So to answer your 2 questions:

1. If your files are going to be changed frequently, it's better to use a CMS.
2. It will be time consuming to create new files & add the necessary tags, etc in it every time.

Having said that, the uses of a CMS span much beyond the above 2.